# Ambiguous type variable from use of array freeze in ST monad

Tags: arrays, haskell

Following code creates array, initializes, then returns immutable array.

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as IA

createCustomeInitializedArray = do
  arr <- newArray (0,10) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
  -- some mutation writeArray arr 0 1 etc
  iarr <- freeze arr -- :: ST s (IA.IArray Array s)
  return iarr
```

`iarr <- freeze arr` causes type error

```
> No instance for (IA.IArray b0 Int) arising from a use of `freeze'
>     The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
```

I have tried commented out type signature and other variations, no luck so far. Please include the thought process involving how to fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has the following most general type:

```
createCustomeInitializedArray :: IA.IArray a Int => ST s (a Int Int)
```

This has a typeclass constraint `IA.IArray a Int` in it. This is a bit tricky actually, as it applies a typeclass partially in the second argument to a fixed type. Haskell98 doesn't allow this; GHC does if you enable the `-XFlexibleContexts` extension. Apart from that, this is obviously a polymorphic type, but because `createCustomeInitializedArray` has no (explicit) arguments, the compiler would like to make it a [constant applicative form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form), via the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). I.e. it refuses to infer a polymorphic type, you need to request it with an explicit signature. Using top-level signatures is an extremely good idea anyway, so do that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
createCustomeInitializedArray :: IA.IArray a Int => ST s (a Int Int)
createCustomeInitializedArray = do
    arr <- newArray (0,10) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
    -- ...
    iarr <- freeze arr
    return iarr
```

I'd add that this local signature you have for `newArray (0,10) 0` doesn't do quite what it looks: Haskell type variables aren't scoped, so the `s` there knows nothing about the `s` from the outlying state; the following is more faithful to what the compiler sees:

```
createCustomeInitializedArray :: IA.IArray a Int => ST s (a Int Int)
createCustomeInitializedArray = do
    arr <- newArray (0,10) 0 :: ST s₁ (STArray s₁ Int Int)
    -- ...
```

So it makes the local action fully polymorphic independent of `s` from the outside, only to then instantiate it to that state argument. Well, this is actually no problem in this particular example, but generally it can be a nasty issue (in particular, constraints on the outer `s` aren't propagated to the inner one). Hence this is the code I'd recommend:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

createCustomeInitializedArray :: ∀ s a . IA.IArray a Int => ST s (a Int Int)
createCustomeInitializedArray = do
  arr <- newArray (0,10) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
  -- ...
  iarr <- freeze arr
  return iarr
```

This can also be written a bit more concisely as

```
  arr :: STArray s Int Int <- newArray (0,10) 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you didn't give a signature for `createCustomInitializedArray`. And due to the [Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) Haskell will try to infer a concrete type for `createCustomInitializedArray`. However it can't, because `freeze` is polymorphic in it's result.

There are four ways to solve this:

1. Provide a monomorphic type signature for `createCustomInitializedArray`. Eg.: `ST s (Array Int Int)`
2. Annotate `iarr` with a concrete type like this:

   ```
   return (iarr :: Array Int Int)
   ```
3. Provide a polymorphic type signature for `createCustomInitilizedArray`.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
   ...
   createCustomInitializedArray :: IA.IArray a Int => ST s (a Int Int)
   ...
   ```
4. Enable the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language extension to let Haskell infer the polymorphic type. I think this would be the least favorable option because you should provide type signatures for all your top-level functions anyway.

Comment: Adding only `iarr <- freeze arr :: ST s (Array Int Int)` doesn't work. Other solutions are working.

Comment: Right, you _can't_ make a monomorphic signature for an `ST` action (without making it unusable, since `runST` is rank-2 polymorphic).

Answer (score 0):

Just for a reminder. Using vector seems a lot easier to me, less knowledge required.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M
import Data.Vector.Unboxed
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad

createCustomeInitializedArray :: ST s (Vector Int)
createCustomeInitializedArray = do
     arr <- M.new 10
     -- ... 
     iarr <- freeze arr
     return iarr
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `freezeSTArray` from `GHC.Arr` instead of `freeze` to specify ambigous type:

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as IA
import GHC.Arr(freezeSTArray)

createCustomeInitializedArray = do
  arr <- newArray (0,10) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
  -- ...
  freezeSTArray arr
```